# RBAC configuration on solaris10

Tags: solaris

I am looking for RBAC configuration on solaris10 to achieve the below:

```
user=jon

group=jtu

jon is owner of /opt/app

user=ken

group=jtu

ken is owner of /data
```

on Linux I have added the below line

```
%jtu ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/*, /usr/bin/*
```

so that jon is able to access /data/tmp and delete files.

This doesn't work on solaris10 since there is no sudo by default.

How to configure RBAC in solaris10 for jon to be able to delete files in /data/tmp?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a palaver ...

First you need to work out which commands jon needs to run with different privilege

We'll assume that ken's uid is 1107 as we're going to give jon the ability to remove files and directories as if he were ken

Once you have the list add those commands to `/etc/security/exec_attr` using your favorite
text editor like so

```
jonpriv:solaris:cmd:::/usr/bin/rm:uid=1107
jonpriv:solaris:cmd:::/usr/bin/rmdir:uid=1107
```

Create an authorization for jonpriv by adding the following to `/etc/security/auth_attr`

```
solaris.jonpriv.:::An authorization for jon::help=
```

Now create a profile for jon by editing `/etc/security/prof_attr`

```
jonpriv:::jons profile.:auths=solaris.jonpriv
```

finally give jon access to the profile

```
usermod -P jonpriv jon
```

jon can now use `rm` and `rmdir` as if he were ken thus

```
pfexec rm  some_file

pfexec rmdir some_directory
```

If it were me doing this for real I'd seriously consider installing sudo from [**sunfreeware**](http://www.sunfreeware.com/)

Comment: thank you for replying lain..i shall try this out and get back to you.

Comment: it didnt work for me :(

Comment: At which point does it not work - I just noticed a mistake in the usermod line and have fixed it in my answer.